# SharePoint Migration - Company aquisition

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, cross-domain

I work for a small company(abc) as a SharePoint(SP2010 version) Admin. Our company is aquired by a another company(xyz). Now we are looking for migrating the content from abc to xyz.I am looking for some advice on the things we should be doing before the SharePoint migration like network connection, active directory migration etc.The things that lay the ground for SharePoint migration.

NOTE: xyz company is planning to build SharePoint 2016 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you get an understanding of what you have in your current SharePoint environment.  Two tools to consider:

1. [Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7826)
2. [Ledger](https://github.com/threewill/Ledger)

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

[Things to do before migrating](http://www.softwebsolutions.com/resources/things-to-do-before-migrating-to-sharepoint-2016.html)

I would also, by my experience, recommend that you audit all your SharePoint and check what you are really using. We found stuff here that nobody modified for 12 years! Ok, it may take a while to verify what you can or can't throw away but it's a long term benefit.
I used this code(SP 2010) to run trough all the site collections of a web application and find out what's not in use for a long time. See if it works for you.

```
  function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) 
        { 
          $today = Get-Date -format g

            $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl 

            foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 

            { 
                # varre todas as listas de cada web
                foreach ($list in $web.Lists) 
                { 
                    # remove lists that are hidden, master page/list template/theme/web part galleries e style libraries
                    if( $list.Hidden -eq $false -and $list.Title -ne "Style Library" -and $list.Title -ne "Master Page Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "List Template Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "Theme Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "Web Part Gallery")
                        {                       
                                                        foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
                            { 



                        $modified = $item["Modified"]
                        $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
                        $age = $TimeSpan.days
                        $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)
                        # definicao do quais informacoes serao puxadas
                            $data = @{ 
                                "Type" = "Item"
                                "Site" = $site.Url 
                                "Web" = $web.Url 
                                "List" = $list.Title 
                                "ID" = $item.ID 
                                "URL" = $item.Url 
                                "Title" = $item.Title 
                                "Created" = $item["Created"] 
                                "Last Modified" = $item["Modified"]
                                "Time without update" = $age

                                     } 
                                     New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"

                        } 

                        $modified = $list.LastItemModifiedDate
                        $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
                        $age = $TimeSpan.days
                        $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)

                        $dataList = @{ 
                                "Type" = "List"
                                "Site" = $site.Url 
                                "Web" = $web.Url 
                                "List" = $list.Title 
                                "ID" = $list.ID 
                                "URL" = "n/a" 
                                "Title" = $list.Title 
                                "Created" = $list.Created 
                                "Last Modified" = $list.LastItemModifiedDate
                                "Time without update" = $age
                                     } 
                                     New-Object PSObject -Property $dataList | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"
                    }
            } 

                    $modified = $web.LastItemModifiedDate
                        $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
                        $age = $TimeSpan.days
                        $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)

             $dataWeb = @{
                "Type" = "Web"
                "Site" = $site.Url 
                "Web" = $web.Url 
                "List" = "n/a" 
                "ID" = $web.ID 
                "URL" = $web.Url 
                "Title" = $web.Title 
                "Created" = $web.Created 
                "Last Modified" = $web.LastItemModifiedDate
                "Time without update" = $age
                        }

                # cria um objeto com as informacoes
                New-Object PSObject -Property $dataWeb | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"
                $web.Dispose(); 
        } 
            $site.Dispose()
    }
```

Just call the function passing the web application URL.

Another thing I would avise is to start with whatever is used the most. See what the employees are really involved with and start from there. That's probably where you will find the most trouble and from there should be easy.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your response. However I am looking some advice on things other than SharePoint like network connection, DNS, Domain trust, AD migration etc.

Comment: And also since the XYZ is planning to go for SP 2016, I am planning to install a new SP 2016 Farm in XYZ's domain to begin with. So my other specific question related to SharePoint content migration is does it makes sense to move our SP 2010 servers to XYZ domain and then do the migration to 2016 (Of course migrating to SP 2013 first and then 2016) or buy a migration tool to migrate from XYZ domain directly to SharePoint 2016.